# How to automatically login to ssh serve on opening new terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a vncsession running on server. Now, whenever I open a new terminal, I have to ssh to another server.
Till now I have been able to setup ssh such that it doesn't ask for password for this particular server. But I have not been able to automatically do this in new terminal. If I add the ssh command to .tcshrc it goes into recursive loop - ssh into server, execute .tcshrc, ssh to server, so on.

I'm using Linux, cshell, Gnome setup.

Comment: What terminal are you using? cshell?

Comment: And if both boxes have the same .tcshrc file? Else this would mean you would connect to your own box again and not to the remote server...

Comment: @DipSwitch
I am using cshell. Updated in OP.
Actually I'm using tchrc file from my home directory that gets mounted on both boxes(at /home/my_username). So, yes, I'm using same tcshrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a hostname check or other check that allow you to recognize the difference between the client and the target. I don't know cshell scripting but in SH you would want to do something like:

```
# Shell:
if [ $HOSTNAME == "vncserver" ]; then
    ssh $TARGET_BOX;
fi;

# Cshell:
if ( $HOSTNAME == 'vncserver' ) then
    ssh $TARGET_BOX;
endif
```

This would enforce that only the svnserver would ssh to the remote system and the remote system won't ssh to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use ssh-agent and [keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) that works like a charm and allows keeping some safety on your servers. Here is [another keychain](http://hornetbzz.developpez.com/tutoriels/debian/ssh/keychain/) tutorial (sorry, written only in french). Just putting your keychain commands in your bashrc or profile that runs at tty start.